# no matches for kind "GitHubSource" in version "sources.eventing.knative.dev/v1alpha1"

Tags: github, knative

**Describe the bug**
Hi, I followed this guide to test githubsource.
 -> [knative/GitHubSource](https://knative.dev/docs/eventing/samples/github-source/)

But I got this error.

```
error: unable to recognize "github-source.yaml": no matches for kind "GitHubSource" in version "sources.eventing.knative.dev/v1alpha1"
```

**To Reproduce**
step :

1. Install CRDs

```sh
$ kubectl apply --selector knative.dev/crd-install=true \
--filename https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.11.0/serving.yaml \
--filename https://github.com/knative/eventing/releases/download/v0.11.0/release.yaml \
--filename https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.11.0/monitoring.yaml
```

2. Install Resources

```sh
$ kubectl apply --filename https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.11.0/serving.yaml \
--filename https://github.com/knative/eventing/releases/download/v0.11.0/release.yaml \
--filename https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.11.0/monitoring.yaml
```

and following this guide ->  [knative/GitHubSource](https://knative.dev/docs/eventing/samples/github-source/)

I got error in "Create Event Source for GitHub Events"

**Knative release version**
v0.11

[image]

**Additional context**
According to this [article](https://knative.dev/docs/eventing/#sources), I can can list all existing Sources with `kubectl get sources`. But I can not find any sources.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [knative/eventing issue 2376](https://github.com/knative/eventing/issues/2376) (opened, I supposed, by the OP) includes an explanation from Vincent ([`houshengbo`](https://github.com/houshengbo)):

Vincent refers to [Knative Eventing / Sources](https://knative.dev/docs/eventing/#sources), about how to install the eventing sources.

> GitHubSource is one of them, and all the [available sources are be found here](https://knative.dev/docs/eventing/sources/index.html).
>   The repo is https://github.com/knative/eventing-contrib.
>
> However, there should be instruction on how to install the sources: [Install Knative Eventing](https://knative.dev/docs/eventing/samples/github-source/index.html).
>   Those instructions also install the default eventing sources, including the GitHubSource we'll use.
>
> I have not found any.
>
> I guess you need to install it by
>
> ```
> kubectl apply -f https://github.com/knative/eventing-contrib/releases/download/v0.11.0/github.yaml
> ```
>
> for 0.11.0.